# Can I share Wii demos with friends?

Tags: nintendo-wii

It seems Wii demos are only available for a limited time.

It is possible to store them on SD cards and share them with friends if I've got one my friend failed to download before it was removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Every Wii download is tied to its respective console, whether it's free or not.